# CSS overlay color with jinja2

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I want to overlay image with color in jinja2.

list_img.html

```
{% for imgAlt, imgSrc in display_img %}
    <div class="img-display-div">
        <img src="{{ imgSrc|e }}" alt="{{ imgAlt|e }}" class="img-display">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried on css using 'z-index' and 'background-color'

like this

```
.img-display-div {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
.img-display {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

This didn't work. image goes upon background-color.
 I think jinja2 make this not work. I tried on jQuery, too.

like this

```
$(".img-display").css({
    "background-color" : "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
});
```

This didn't work either.
how can I overcome this?

Comment: *"I think jinja2 make this not work"* - on what basis? Have you looked at the resulting HTML to see if it's what you expected? Tried adjusting the CSS in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.img-display-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.img-display-div:after {
  content:'';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```